# Is it possible to determine who had accessed filed in a public folder of my google drive?

Tags: google-drive

I have a public folder with a number of files in my Google Drive. Anyone with a link can access the files. Is it possible to get any file access history ?

Comment: What research have you done? I'd guess that Google has documentation on this. Have you searched for and reviewed that?

Answer (score 1):

You can see [who edited a file](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045) in Google Drive and Docs, with the *caveat* that, "history for Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides is different than history for .pdf files, images, and other files stored in Drive."

However, you cannot know who **accessed** a file, if the file was accessed *via* a public link, rather than by logging into a Google account. Consider someone sending your link to a friend, who then uses that link, perhaps by VPN, to download the document without need to log into Google. How would Google identify that second user?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Views tracking is not supported by Google Drive, Google Drive for Desktop, or Google Drive for the Web.

---

Screenshots of Google Drive for Desktop and for the Web

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Google Drive for Desktop shows the file activity. [image: Google Drive for Desktop (Mac) Files activity] | File contextual menu MacOS Ventura with Google Drive for Desktop [image: File contextual menu MacOS Ventura with Google Drive for Desktop] |
| File sharing in Google Drive for Web [image: File sharing in Google Drive for Web] |  |
| File information panel, Details tab, in Google Drive for Web [image: in Google Drive for Web] | File information panel, Activity tab, in Google Drive for Web [image: in Google Drive for Web] |
| Document view for anonymous user [image: in Google Drive for Web] | Document view for signed in user [image: in Google Drive for Web] |
| Google Drive information panel after a document was added and viewed by an anonymous user [image: in Google Drive for Web] |  |

It's impossible to track all the visits to your publically shared folder with anyone from the web, including anonymous users. Instead, you might want to create a website or use a service that allows you to do that.

You might see file changes from [View activity & file versions](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045?hl=en) (copy-pasted as plain text).

> ##### View past activity
>
> 1. On your computer, go to drive.google.com.
> 2. On the left click My Drive.
> 3. In the upper right, click Info Info.
> 4. To see recent changes, click Activity.
> 5. To see the activity of a specific file or folder, click the file or folder.
> 6. To see older changes, scroll down on the right side.

You might see when a file was viewed by users under certain conditions. From [View the activity on your Google Docs, Sheets & Slides](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7378739?hl=en) (copy-pasted as plain text)
NOTE: This article is automatically tailored for users signed into a Google account.

###### For consumer accounts (i.e., `username@gmail.com`)

> If someone with a work or school account shares a file with you, they may be able to see it when you view it.

###### For Google Workspace accounts

NOTE: `username@example.com` was used instead of my Google Workspace email address

> You can see which of your collaborators have viewed and commented on your file in Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides with your account through work or school: username@example.com.
>
> Note: You’ll only see activity from people in your organization or the people you see in Share and then Advanced.

---

While file view tracking is not a supported feature by Google Drive, it might still achieve your goal. For this, you might have to take advantage of expiring shared links to be able to track multiple visits from the same user, as once they access a folder or file, they will appear in *Shared with me* (a section from Google Drive) so they might not need to use your tracking website to access a second time the folder.

From [Tips to access and find your files](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/13005112?hl=en) from Google Workspace Learning Center (copy-paste as plain text, minimal formatting. Follow the above link to enjoy the original formatting, links, etc.)

> ##### Set an expiration date for file access

...

> ###### Add, change, or delete an expiration date
>
> 1. Open a file in Google Drive.
> 2. Click Share.
> 3. Find the user and next to the user's name, click the Down arrow Down and thenAdd expiration.
> 4. To accept the 30-day expiration date, click Send.
> 5. If you want to change the default expiration date, for Access expires, click Edit "" and select the expiration date from the calendar.
> 6. (Optional) To remove the expiration, click Remove expiration.
> 7. Click Done and then Send.

The easier alternative might be to use a URL-shortening service that allows you to update the target destination. You might have to use a low-code / no-code platform or a third-party service to make this a feasible solution.

Among the options, there is Google Apps Script. It offers multiple advantages, but it requires to know programming using JavaScript. If you are looking for something that not requires coding, look at the Google Workspace Marketplace. On the Web search for no code / low code. A couple of examples are Zappier and IFTTT (if-this-then-that). If you prefer to keep everything on the Google "cloud", look at AppSheet. Some in the middle are Google Sheets and Google Sites.

Please remember that Stack Exchange has a site focused on handling software recommendations: [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

#### Related

##### From Software Recommendations

- [Track changes in a shared project folder](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14073/83591)
- [URL shortener with good statistics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13421/83591)